# How to clean clothes that remain "dusty"

Tags: clothing

Dust keeps flying out of my clothes even after I wash them. I tried duck tape and trying to vacuum them. That did not work. What else can I try?

Comment: You might mention how you store your clothes. What sort of environment are you in? If for example, if you're in the Sahara, the answer may differ than if you're in the amazon.

Comment: you tried vacuum ! . I think that the problem is with few clothes not all of them. I would suggest to replace the clothes.

Answer (score 3):

You may find that the dirt is coming in your water. Grab a cup of the water with which you're washing your clothes and let it sit for a few days to see if it any dirt settles in the bottom of the cup.

Answer (score 1):

After laundry, you should fold your clothes and put them in drawer of a dresser or something like that. It might just be because your room or the place you live is kind of dusty, and the best way to deal with that is to vacuum your room more frequently, and if dusty clothes is such an issue, you should keep them in drawers rather than hanging in a closet.

Comment: I triad that but it doesn't work as soon as it comes out of the dray tumbler dust is all over it.everyone thing am nasty bc of this dust so I just stay at home  it's so frustrating people talkig behind my back saying he don't wash his clothes.also I have essecive sweating proplem which just makes it worse

Comment: @harmit then it's time to check your tumbler, call a repair service or get a new one.

Comment: I agree with @Stephie that if putting your clothes in the tumbler is a necessary step, then you need to get your tumbler fixed or get a new one. Otherwise you can try air drying them, and put them inside a drawer as soon as it's completely dried. As a side note, it's always helpful to keep your clothes dust free if you are willing to vacuum and /or wipe clean your room on a regular basis. It's hard to keep things dust free if the environment it's in is too dusty to start with.

Answer (score 1):

The dust and lint trap in the tumbler might be full or nearly plugged and not removing lint and dust as your clothes dry. The tube from the tumbler to the outside vent must be clear from all blockage to work. Sometimes there are birds and rodent nests that must be removed to have the tumbler working efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Hanging them in front of a powerful fan should blow a lot of the dust away. Or you could do it the natural way, and hang them outside on a windy day.  Just make sure they are well secured! Hitting them while they are hanging up (in the wind or near the fan) will help too.

Answer (score -1):

You likely have faulty carpet in your home. I recently discovered this is what I have. The dust is microfibres being actively shed into the air from your carpet. Tiny white plastic fibres less than 3mm and statically charged so they stick to everything. I think this is a problem that will become a big deal in public mind in near future. It’s carcinogenic too. You need to get the carpet out before anything you do will have impact and it will probably take another 6 months of dedicated air filters, ionisers and hoovering with shaking and beating clothes outside to remove the dust (all upholstery, blankets, bedding, curtains etc). To be honest, I’d think it easier to move house and change all your clothing for new. It’s a scandal, no one should be exposed to these toxins when buying home fittings like carpet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is bit extreme for dust in clothes. Just a bit. Glad you didn't suggest to burn all clothes and become a nudist. (Kind of same scale as what's being suggested here.)